# Can't load main class in Maven Java project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have Java Maven project in Eclipse IDE. After I moved to newer Eclipse I found red icon with cross under my project:

[image]

I did Maven clean, but that not helped. After this procedure I even can't start my `Main` class. I have error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class play.Main
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Open the "Problems" view, and read the error messages.

Comment: Did you try to update maven project? (Alt-F5)

Comment: Maven update  solved problem with red icon. Since I had more not updated project in workspace I still couldn't run project until I update them all. Why? What does Maven do during update?

Answer (score 0):

Open the shell, go to the project folder and run `mvn compile`

Comment: I run eclipse in Windows, so there is no shell